# Calculating needed padding size to have a bit string having length which is a multiple of 8

Tags: python

```
def asn1_integer(i):
  if  i >= 0:

    i = decimal_to_binary(i)
    if len(i) < 8:
        i = ('0'* (8 - len(i))) + i
```

I want the length of `i` to be a multiple of 8. So I need to have a function that adds `'0'`s to the beginning of a bit string, relative to the `8k - len(i) = number_of_additional_bits` equation.

P.s. `bin`, `hex`, `str`, `int`, `bytearray`, `divmod` functions are prohibited for this task.

`decimal_to_binary(i)` converts a decimal to binary equivalent by using the bitwise operators.

Comment: Is `i` a string or an integer, as originally passed into the function? Furthermore, what's the return type of `decimal_to_binary()`?

Comment: So? What is your question? You seem to have a code for the job? Is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to figure out the next multiple of 8 that's greater than your string's length. Use `divmod` to divide the current length by 8. If there's a remainder, your final string needs to be of a length `(quotient + 1) * 8`. If there isn't a remainder, you just need `quotient * 8`

```
i = "11001"
str_len = len(i)
req_len, remainder = divmod(str_len, 8)
if remainder: req_len += 1
req_len *= 8
```

Then, pad your string to `req_len`:

```
i = f'{i:>0{req_len}}' # '00011001'
```

The `f'...'` construct is called a *f-string* and is an easy way to do string interpolation. [More info](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)